# Updating the expiry date of a cookie in ASP.NET API controller action

Tags: cookies, asp.net-web-api

Struggling to find an answer to this. I set a cookie which essentially allows me to track a visitors shopping cart. Setting the cookie is fine but I can't find a way of updating the expiry date, so that each time the user does something cart related it updates to 90 days in the future. My code below. This is the AddToCart API method in question.

```
[ActionName("AddToCart")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage AddToCart(int id)
{
    HttpResponseMessage msg = new HttpResponseMessage();
    CookieHeaderValue header = Request.Headers.GetCookies("visitor").FirstOrDefault();
    VisitorViewModel visitor;

    if (header == null)
    {
        visitor = _visitorManager.Create().ToViewModel();
        header = new CookieHeaderValue("visitor", visitor.Cookie);
        header.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(90);
        msg.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { header });
    }
    else
    {
        visitor = _visitorManager.Get(header["visitor"].Value).ToViewModel();
        header.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(90);
        msg.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { header });
    }

    _cartManager.AddToCart(id, visitor.ID);

    return msg;

}
```

If the user has not got a cookie yet it adds the cookie correctly, but if the cookie already exists I end up with a second cookie which is kind of what I'd expect based on the code. Just can't find a way to update the existing client cookie.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: err .. ok .. so common courtesy is a no no .. weird but I will edit.

Comment: It's a common courtesy in a conversation. But we're not having a conversation. This is a Q&A site, and quite unique. Please read the linked meta question.

Comment: the irony of people spending an inordinate amount of time considering whether the word Hi should be at the start of a post because they want more time to answer questions is not lost on me .. but fair enough I consider myself informed :)

Comment: It's a question of removing fluff from questions and answers - and educating other users to do the same - in order to improve the clarity of the questions and to improve the likelihood of a search engine finding the correct question when someone searches for it in the future. This is in contrast with forum sites or newsgroups, where the focus is answering the question before us, as opposed to answering the same question for posterity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was to do with the path of the cookie. By ensuring that I set the path to "/" in all setting and retrieving of the cookie the cookie was updated correctly.